# Can't display view in playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Code:

```
import UIKit

import PlaygroundSupport

let simpleView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 450))

simpleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = simpleView

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

I can see the view when I click the "eyes icon" but when I open the assistant view it displays nothing.
Can anybody tell my what I need to do?
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt5FG.png)

Answer (score 1):

I work it out.

Firstly I update the Xcode to 8.3.2, but not work, then I delete all the DerivedData cache and create a new project, copy the code, then it works